# Module that edits existing product names in magento?

Tags: php, magento, module

Please I am trying to create a module in magento that edits the products' name by concatenating the existing product names with randomly generated numbers.

> $model = Mage::getModel('catalog/product') ->load(1111) //getting
> product model
>
> $collection = $model->getCollection(); //products collection
>
> foreach ($collection as $product) //loop for getting products
>
> {
>
> $model->load($product->getId());
>
> $pname = $product->getName();
>
> $this->model = Mage::getModel('catalog/product');
>
> $new_name = $pname.' '.rand(1000,5000);
>
> $this->model->setName($new_name);
>
> }

This is my code, I am trying to create a module to achieve this functionality without editing the core files or using the admin panel.

Comment: You should be able to do this with the [magento api](http://www.magentocommerce.com/api/soap/catalog/catalogProduct/catalog_product.update.html)

Comment: @Orangepill there is my code, its a technical task that has to be done that way and its urgent too. thanks in advance guys

Comment: are you getting any errors with this?

Comment: and I can't tell if you are trying to change the name on an existing model or create a new model

Comment: have u added $this->model->save(); ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sorry but your code is ugly.

If you want to use collection (that is a good way to access data from a list of object) you must not use a ->load() (very expensive and should be used only when accessing data for a single object, like a product page)

Try this code instead :

```
    $collection = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection(); //products collection
    $collection->addAttributeToSelect('name'); //retrieve only product name (optimising SQL)

    foreach ($collection as $product) //loop for getting products
    {
        $pname = $product->getName(); 
        $new_name = $pname.' '.rand(1000,5000);
        $product->setName($new_name);
        $product->save(); // you missed that
    }
```

If you have a high number or product, you could also make a single SQL query with the SQL CONCAT() function ...

Comment: Thank you @Bixi, I am just starting out in magento module development and yes your code does make more sense. I have the basic directory structures setup but which event observer should be called before editing the product names with that code ?

Comment: You can use `catalog_product_save_before` but it will require you to rework your code. Be carefull if you're, using ImportExport to Import your products : models events are not called.

Comment: Yes, they are included in the config.xml

Answer (score 0):

> class Digital_GoogleMpn_Model_Observer {
>
> ```
> public function googleMpn(Varien_Event_Observer $observer)
> {
> ```
>
> $product = $observer->getEvent()->getProduct();
>
> ```
>     $pname = $product->getName();         
>
> $google_mpn = rand(1000,5000);
>   
>     $new_name = "{$pname}.' '.{$google_mpn}"; 
>   
>     $product->setName($new_name);
>   
>     $product->save(); 
>
>   
> }      }
> ```

Comment: @Bixi, this is what I have restructured my current code to look like but the module still doesn't work. The observer in use is the `catalog_product_save_before` which has been set in the xml file. The product object is meant to set the product name to the `$new_name variable`

Comment: don't ->save() yourself has your juste before the saving of a product (before_save observer). If you do that, you could go in an infinite loop. If it doesn't work, make sure your obsrver is called by adding Mage::log() logs

Comment: Have removed the `$product->save()` but the code still does not work. so how do you use the Mage::log() ?

Comment: search on google a bit : Mage::log() + http://www.yireo.com/tutorials/magento/magento-administration/666-analysing-logfiles-with-magento